# How can I run a iOS App which has been built on MacOSX using the `Test` build containing `XCTest` unit tests from Linux to a iOS device

Tags: ios, xcode, xctest, iosdeployment, libimobiledevice

I have been researching this for the past few weeks and working to try to see if how it is possible to setup https://github.com/facebook/WebDriverAgent and in particular `XCTest`'s to be able to be deployed and ran in `test` mode from `Linux`.

At this point I can use `xcodebuild` `build-for-testing` or `test` which will build the `WDA` App (`XCTest` unit tests) on `MacOSX` and then deploy it onto the phone and run it as `Test`.  This allows the `XCTest` libraries to be loaded and then allows interaction between `WDA` and automation on the phone via the `XCTest` framework.

I am wondering if there is some way to either extend `ideviceinstaller`, `libimobiledevice` or `ios-deploy` or some other solution to support pushing the `Test` build to a real `iOS` device from `Linux`.

**Main Question**

- How can I run a iOS `App` which has been built on MacOSX using the `Test` build containing `XCTest` unit tests from `Linux` to a `iOS device`?

I have seen commercial products which provide this so there must be a way to do this but I am currently stuck trying to determine how to do this.